# Showing that a function lies in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

In an exam today I had the following problem:
\begin{align}
f_s(x) = \exp(-\vert x \vert^2)\vert x \vert^s
\end{align}
for $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $s\geq 0 $ or for $x\in \mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{0\} $ and $s < 0 $. When is $f_s$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$? I really have no idea how to show that a specific function lies in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for general $p$...

Comment: Surely you have a feeling for this? I mean for $s>0$ that exponential decay has to scare the bejesus out of that puny little polynomial thingie, right?

Comment: If you can't show something for general $p$, try doing it for specific $p$ (so $p = 2,3$), and see if there's some pattern.

Comment: no sorry, I really have no feeling about this... even not for the case $p=2$ for example

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is a radial function, we have
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^d}|f(x)|^p\,dx=\int_{\Bbb R^d}e^{-p|x|^2}|x|^{ps}\,dx=C_d\int_0^\infty e^{-pr^2}r^{ps+d-1}\,dr.
$$
Can you finish now?

Comment: Why radial function? I do not see the way to finish...

Comment: Well, $f$ depends on $|x|$. The integral is convergent at $\infty$ for all values of $p$ and $s$, because the exponential "kills" the power of $r$. The integral is convergent at $0$ when  $ps+d-1>-1$, that is $ps+d>0$.

Comment: What's anime?  .

Comment: Probably the automatic corrector (which is set to spanish by default). I do not remember what I pretended to write.

Answer (score 0):

$\exp(-|x|^2)$ belongs to the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for every $n$, hence there is no integrability issue far from the origin and the given function belongs to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as soon as $|x|^{sd}$ is integrable in a neighbourhood of the origin. On the other hand, integrating along shells,
$$ \int_{|x|\leq 1}|x|^{ps}\,d\mu = \int_{0}^{1}\rho^{ps} A_{d}\rho^{d-1}\,d\rho$$
where $A_d$ is the surface area of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$, namely $\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)}$.
 The last integral is convergent as soon as $ps+d>0$ i.e. as soon as $\color{red}{s>-\frac{d}{p}}$.